# Fake ProjectTypeGuid to be ignored by VS

Tags: visual-studio, monodevelop, projects-and-solutions

I have a VC# projects created by a custom MonoDevelop build, that have special guid in `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element of the project file. If I try to open that project in VS2013 then it will fail with a warning of unsupported project type.

However, if I remove that special guid and leave only `{FAE04EC0-301F-11d3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` (there are 2 guids there initially) the project would open just fine in VS as a regular VC# Library project.

Is there any way that I could create a "fake" "null-project type" for that other guid entry, so that VS would just think that it knows that project type and open that project? It seems that besides that project type guid it's just a regular VC# project.

If that would somehow help here the message VS shows then trying to open project:

> The application which this project type is based on was not found.
>   Please try this link for further information:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=guid

The product in question is a PSM Studio (a part of PlayStation Mobile SDK) which is based on ModoDevelop 2.8. Removing the guid `{69878862-DA7D-4DC6-B0A1-50D8FAB4242F}` will make the tool unhappy. However I want to be able to use VS as an editor without necessity to modify project files.

Comment: Don't force us to guess at the incompatible {guid}.  If it is just a plain C# project then you don't appear to need it.  You need to document what happens when you try to open the patched .vcproj file in MonoDevelop.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't need it, exactly! However it's required by MonoDevelop with which I must retain compatibility. I just want VS to ignore it as much as possible.

Comment: Why does MonoDevelop need it? If it's normal C# project just remove custom GUID and MD will work fine... If it's not a secret what is subtype maybe we can better help if we know that...

Comment: @DavidKarlaš of course, silly me! I've updated the question.